# LINQ query returns no values from successfully added database

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning how to connect database to your C# application.

I encountered a problem: I added a new DataSource (one of databases on my PC), it loaded successfully, I can create program using data from it. But when I try to do the following (LINQ query):

```
MyDatabaseDataSet context = new MyDatabaseDataSet();

var data = from d in context.SomeTable.AsEnumerable()
           select d;
```

It returns no results... I am new to this, so I don't know where to look for problems.

Any help will be appreciated...

EDIT: I ran SQL Profiler and it doesn't seem to do anything when I run this code... But I don't understand why...

Comment: What means "it returns no results"? What have you tried to access the rows? What does `data.Any()?`  return? If it's `false` that `DataTable` is empty.

Comment: How do you check 1) that `data` does not have any entities 2) that you actually have data in the mapped table of the database you are connected to

Comment: Maybe `SomeTable` is empty?

Comment: @TimSchmelter @David `data.Any()` returns `false`... but in SQL Server I can see, that I have thousands of rows.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have done it in multiple ways, one of them was using debugger and Watch window (adding Watch to the variable). It's my own database, so I just open SSMS and see, that the table isn't empty.

The problem also occurs with other tables...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Are you sure you're looking at the same data?  What's your application's connection string?  How are you connecting to SQL Server manually?  Can you use SQL Server Profiler on your database when the application runs to ensure it's querying the same table/database that you expect?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: a `DataTable` is just an in memory collection like a list or array. It is not connected  with your database table. If you fill it you have to show how, otherwise we cant help to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe there are supressed exceptions. You may check your exception settings and enable some of them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, so if it's not connected with my database, then how to do that? I added this database using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884(v=vs.90).aspx manual. I didn't fill any table...

Comment: I would check and make sure that you have passed a connection string in your constructor. This should be in your web config or app config.       public MyContext()
            : base("MyContextConnectionString")
        {
        }

Comment: I tried, but this constructor doesn't accpets any arguments.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: What constructor doesn't accept arguments?  Data contexts in Entity Framework accept connection strings as an argument.  It's currently *possible* that you're not using the connection you think you're using, and instead using some auto-created local database for the application (which would be empty).  So the goal here is to verify the connection string the application is using.  Profiling the target database while the application queries it would also definitely verify this, as well as show you the exact query EF created and executed.

Comment: @David `MyDatabaseDataSet()` - this one doesn't...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Well then what is `MyDatabaseDataSet`?  Is it something other than an Entity Framework data context?

Comment: I don't know... I just added `MyDatabase` accordingly to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884(v=vs.90).aspx . It automatically switched name to `MyDatabaseDataSet`, don't know why, and now I can create instances of it. It's all I know.

Comment: I think I know where the problem is - IDE has created class for me and I just create new instnce of it, completely empty. Now - how to fill it with actual values?

Comment: "Updated: October 2008" - If you can use anything you want to, may have a look at entity framework.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to rename database.  SSMS comes with SQL Server. The tool that added the database used the filename as the default.  The SSMS explorer will allow you to change database name, but then you will have to change the properties of your project to agree with the name in SQL Server.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: That set of steps involves connecting to a Northwind sample database file.  Is that your actual database?  It seems like you're using two different databases here.  One that you're looking at in SQL Server Management Studio, and one that is isolated to just your application.  It also seems like you could really be using an updated tutorial.  (Or are you actually stuck using Visual Studio 2008?)

Comment: @David See my previous comment - I think that's the issue. My database was just mapped into class, which I created instance of. So, it must be empty. I just don't know how to fill it (when you pass connection string in constructor, I think it populates all data, but my constructor just doesn't accept any argument). Answering your question: I have connected to one of my databases.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: I'm afraid that none of your comment is really making much sense.  Creating a database connection object (regardless of what framework or technology is used to do it) doesn't "populate all data", or *any* data.  It just creates an object for communicating with the database.  What we are suspecting here is that you're not communicating with the database that you think you are.  And our first recommendation is to at least use something more recent, such as Entity Framework.  Admittedly, I'm not entirely familiar with the very old sample you're using.